# How to Change a users password from MySQL prompt

Tags: mysql

How to Change a users password from MySQL prompt.
bellow is my code

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'hostname' = PASSWORD('my_password');
```

Comment: So, did that work?  What are you asking, or are you just telling us how to do it?

Comment: this code is not work to change my password do i missing something?

Comment: You're missing the part where you tell us what's wrong.  Is this not working?  Do you see any errors?  Can you show us the *exact* errors?

Comment: no i am not getting any error but my prompt just getting close when i press enter after this code.

Answer (score 0):

That should work if you have UPDATE privileges for the mysql database.

Its important to note that the password may be recorded on the server side or in your mysql_history file.